# How to forward all kind of request from ROOT to other web app context with Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I need to forward all kind of request from the ROOT, i.e http://localhost:8080/ to http://localhost:8080/myRoot

Is it possible, do I need to create a redirect servlet? However, I think tomcat can be configured to behave that way?

Comment: **Forward** is only possible within the context of an app however if you want **redirect** then there are many ways of doing that eg: BalusC has shown you one way of redirection.

Comment: @anubhava I see, yes I have done redirect with the help of UrlRewriteFiler (http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/)

Comment: @anubhava I have a new problem though, I need to make sure that even with redirect the url, the browser url that will be shown is not the redirect url but the original request URL, i.e like http://localhost:8080/index.html and not http://localhost:8080/myRoot/index.html

Comment: That's what I meant that **forward** is not possible when switching from one app context to another. And if it is **redirect** then URL in browser will surely change to the new one. Even UrlRewriteFiler will also have same behavior.

Comment: @anubhava however this site tell something about forward: http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/enhancing_your_gwt_application_with I mean, i says that with the approached discussed a web app can be hosted in the ROOT through some form of forward (as I see in the urlwriter.xml rules)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427841/how-to-use-urlrewritefilter-with-gwt-in-tomcat

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much about GWT, however when you tried `type="forward"` in UrlRewriteFiler, did it `forward` or `redirect`?

Comment: @anubhava When I tried it, forward wont work, but redirect works.

Comment: Yes that means what I wrote initially was correct that forward will not work but redirect would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is to use [UrlRewriteFilter](http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/)

Deployed the filter into the ROOT and modified the `urlrewrite.xml` like this:

```
<rule>
    <from>^/$</from>
    <to type="redirect">%{context-path}/myRoot</to>
</rule>
```

And now it works.

Comment: That's also possible :) You only don't need to write a filter yourself.

Comment: If you want to use 'forward' instead of 'redirect', further configuration is required: first, you need to turn on `crossContext` in context.xml, and then modify the to rule here as: `<to type="forward" context="myRoot">/</to>`. There's an issue now with this usage, but it could be workaround, see https://github.com/paultuckey/urlrewritefilter/issues/153

Answer (score 2):

An easy way would be to create a filter something like this

```
@WebFilter("/*")
public class RedirectFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        String uri = request.getRequestURI();
        String query = request.getQueryString();

        if (query != null) {
            uri = uri + "?" + query;
        }

        response.setStatus(301);
        response.setHeader("Location", "/myRoot" + uri);
        // Can also use response.sendRedirect(), but this does 302 by default.
    }

    // ...
}
```

and put it in `Tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/RedirectFilter.class`.

If you're still using Tomcat 6.0 or older, then remove `@WebFilter` annotation and create the `web.xml` accordingly.